# Especificando altura e sexo de alunos com um "while"

Tags: c, algoritmo, if, while

O exercício me pede para ler 20 alunos e suas respectivas alturas e sexo, e, depois, mostrar a média das alturas e quantos homens e mulheres temos.

O que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

```
int main() {
    float altura, media;
    char gen, mediam, mediaf;
    int contador;

    contador = 0;

    printf("Cálculo de alunos e alunas e média de suas alturas\n");
    while (contador < 3) {
        printf("Digite a altura e o sexo do aluno\n");
        scanf("%f", &altura);
        media = media + altura;
        scanf("%s", &gen);
        if (gen = 'm') {
            mediam = mediam + gen;
        } else {
            mediaf = mediaf + gen;
        }
        contador++;


    }

    printf("A média de altura dos alunos é: \n%f", media);
    printf("Temos %s alunos homens e %s alunos mulheres\n", mediam, mediaf);


    return 0;
}+
```

Consegui fazer o programa ler o total da altura dos alunos, porém, quando digito a parte do total de alunos homens e mulheres, a própria linha de ler as alturas dá um erro de *segmentation fault*.

Comment: O enunciado é este mesmo? O código não faz o que está pedindo e faz o que não está.

Comment: É esse sim, consegui fazer com que o código leia a altura. Mas talvez não tenha usado a lógica certa para ler o número de homens e mulheres.

Comment: O enunciado não pede isso.

Comment: Perdão, o enunciado pede a média de altura e quantos homens e mulheres tem. Não percebi que escrevi errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários erros. Se você quer contar o número de homens e mulheres deve incrementar a variável, igual fez em `contador`, afinal elas não deixam de ser um contador. A variável `contador` poderia ser eliminada, mas não acho que compensa.

Os nomes das variáveis estão ruins, porque está chamando de média o que não é uma média, é um acumulador.

Não pode usar `=` para comparação, isto é o operador de atribuição. Para comprar use `==`. E teste todas possibilidades e evite fazer algo com uma informação errada, por isso fiz as condições do `if` mais completas.

A média é só calculada no final.

Havia errados de formatação do `printf()`.

Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float alturas = 0.0f;
    int contador = 0, masculinos = 0, femininos = 0;
    printf("Cálculo de alunos e alunas e média de suas alturas\n");
    while (contador < 3) {
        float altura;
        char gen;
        printf("Digite a altura e o sexo do aluno\n");
        scanf("%f", &altura);
        scanf("%s", &gen);
        if (gen == 'm' || gen == 'M') masculinos++;
        else if (gen == 'f' || gen == 'F') femininos++;
        else continue;
        alturas += altura;
        contador++;
    }
    printf("A média de altura dos alunos é: %f\n", alturas / contador);
    printf("Temos %d alunos homens e %d alunos mulheres\n", masculinos, femininos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uFtLlo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ctwaqecd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RegisterPerson.c).

Comment: Entendi agora, ainda tenho um pouco de dificuldades em relação a criar variáveis... estou praticando isso. Perfeito código, vou estudá-lo mais para ver meus erros e consertar. Obrigado cara!